# Generate a select element for years in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a drop down list that just shows the years from 1990 to 2014.

I've tried:

```
<%= select_tag "year", [1900..2014] %>
```

But I get:

```
<select id="year" name="year">[1900..2014]</select>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are making an array with a single range object in it. `[1900..2014].first #=> 1900..2014`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `options_for_select`

```
<%= select_tag "year", options_for_select(1900..2014) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `()` instead of `[]`, like this:

```
<%= select_tag "year", options_for_select((1900..2014).to_a) %>
```

The expression `[1900..2014]` represents an array whose only element is a range.
Calling `to_a` on a *1..10* range returns `[1,2,3,'...','etc']`.

**Edit:** oops, select_tag, unlike the `f.select` you use insde `form_for` blocks doesn't automatically convert array into option tags, so you need to use `options_for_select`. @dimuch just noted that.

Comment: It's outputting the same thing only without brackets. `<select id="year" name="year">1900..2014</select>`

Comment: See @nicooga's edit - you'll need to tack on a .to_a as well.